# How to run the jquery code only in mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

what do I need to change here to work the code only on mobile devices, and to be disabled on computers?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<ul id="primary-menu">
  <li class="menu-item-has-children">
    <a href="http://example.org">Click me</a>
  </li>
</ul>
</body>
```

```
$( document ).ready(function() {  
  $("ul#primary-menu > li.menu-item-has-children > a").one("click", function(e)     {
     e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device#3540295

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37832280/9357872

Comment: @EvikGhazarian Using screen size to detect mobile devices is a very bad and extremely unreliable approach. Many users resize their browsers all the time for all kinds of reasons. It's only acceptable for design (layout) purposes

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `navigator` object to detect the device.

The `Navigator` object will return something like bellow, then use regex to detect the device.

`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.87 Safari/537.36`

**Sample code.**

```
if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    $("ul#primary-menu > li.menu-item-has-children > a").one("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

Hope this will help.