# Applying jquery code only to mobile device

Tags: jquery

I'm using [fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) on a site and want to style events slightly differently on smaller screen sizes. How can I trigger the code below if a window is below a certain size?

```
eventAfterRender: function(event, element, view) {
    $(element).css('height','10px');
}
```

Comment: Don't use JS, use CSS's `@media` directive

Comment: You probably won’t be able to trigger that event on mobile only, but you can easily wrap what you are doing inside the handler function in a condition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Only run JQuery on mobile view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36454146/only-run-jquery-on-mobile-view)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `$(window).width()` as

```
    var width = $(window).width();
    if (width <= 480) {
      //code for mobile devices
    } else {
      //code for other devices
    }
```

`$(window).width()` gives you the width of the device in pixel and you can use that value to determine the `mobile`, `tablet` or `desktop` devices accordingly and add your device specific code accordingly.

Comment: Please be aware that this would not be responsive. It would be better to apply style changes via css and `@media`

Comment: @MichaelWalter I agree with you but this could be still useful when you want to run some JavaScript or Jquery that applies to specific device configurations.

Answer (score 0):

For smaller screen in jquery you can define the size of window with

```
$(window).width()
```

And make an if condition

```
var windowWidth = $(window).width();
if(windowWidth<768){//Your script if device width is under 768px}
```